# file_get_contents returning string instead of FALSE on fail

Tags: php, return-value, file-get-contents

I was using the following code to determine if a file_get_contents was successful:

```
if($toon = @file_get_contents('http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/magtheridon/ronuburggundy'))
{
}
```

We recently migrated to a new host and we are running php 5.4.8 (im not sure if this is the issue, we had 5.4.7 before).

`$toon = file_get_contents('http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/magtheridon/ronuburggundy');`

Should fail and return FALSE. But instead doing a:

`echo $toon;`

Now prints:

`{"status":"nok", "reason": "Character not found."}`

I do not see where the change that is causing the change in return.

I have a custom php.ini in my directory, but it really only set all allow_url_fopen() to On from the default Off.

Thanks for any input.

No the way I wanted to fix this, and I still don't understand why the behavior suddenly changed.

But the below helper function is now used to check validity of the request.

```
$toon = request_toon("http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/magtheridon/ronburggundy");

function request_toon($url)
{
$toon = @file_get_contents($url);
    if($toon)
    {
    $toon = json_decode($toon);
        if(array_key_exists('status', $toon))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $toon;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` successfully retrieved the content of the URL, I don't know why you'd expect it to return `false`. As a general rule of thumb: you are making an HTTP request to an external system. That's a rather involved and expensive action which can have several possible outcomes. Trying to do all this inline in a condition with a single function all is way too simplistic. Write some more lines of code around this action, enough to handle what you need to handle.

Comment: On our previous host the above method worked perfectly, I say it should fail because there is no json object at battle.net for the given url. `http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/magtheridon/ronuburggundy` should fail, and `http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/magtheridon/ronburggundy` should return a json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to be on the server side. The server is telling you it can't find the character you are looking for. The call to `file_get_contents()` is not failing, so it will not return false.

If you visit the page in your browser [(link)](http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/magtheridon/ronuburggundy) you can see the file does have contents. You will have to test the contents of the return for 'Character not found' and then you will know the search for the character failed.

Comment: I guess my confusion is coming from the behavior of this approach changing. On my previous host, "character not found" was the return contents but it also evaluated to FALSE for some reason. Now on our new host, it is working as described in my question. I do not understand why its behavior suddenly changed between hosts.

Comment: In that case I would have thought that it never worked on your previous host? Some hosts disable it for security reasons.

Comment: On my previous host `allow_url_fopen` was enabled by default, on my new host I had to use a custom php.ini to enable it desired directories, so I wasnt sure if there was another property I had to set to have it behave as it did on my previous host where it would return FALSE instead of the fail string.